# Does AsyncIOMotorCommandCursor.fetch_next prevent a retryable read?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to diagnose a read failure with [motor](https://motor.readthedocs.io) during a Mongo Atlas cluster failover. The Retryable-Reads specification defines that [`aggregate` calls are retryable](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/retryable-reads/retryable-reads.rst#supported-read-operations), but [`Cursor.getMore` is not](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/retryable-reads/retryable-reads.rst#unsupported-read-operations). I have code that looks like this:

```py
cursor = db.foo.aggregate([...])

if not await cursor.fetch_next:
    raise SomeException

doc = cursor.next_object()
```

This code appears to not retry during a cluster failover, because it's internally calling `getMore` *I assume*. I'm not entirely clear whether that's the case or not. Not to mention that [`fetch_next` is deprecated anyway](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/cursors.html#motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorCommandCursor.fetch_next).

Would changing it to this make it a retryable read?

```py
async for doc in cursor:
    break
else:
    raise SomeException
```

Or does this result in the same internal processing, and the problem is elsewhere?

The goal is to try to read the single result document from an aggregation pipeline (there's either one or none) in a retryable manner and raise an exception if there's none.

Comment: What was the error? The retryable reads is quite low level thing that addresses network errors.  If you are fetching a single document, there is no getMore invoked. The document (if exists) is returned within the first batch https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/ac61cf87a911d72b095ea00663e051f6ac148c7a/pymongo/database.py#L374 and aggregation command itself is retryable.

Comment: `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` [...] `pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: example.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused` — I'm not sure if this means the driver _did_ try to reconnect and it failed twice. If that's the case, then Atlas failover during cluster scaling is rather broken…?!

Comment: May be not completely broken but a bit slower than acceptable. The retryable thingie makes only one attempt to reconnect. If the second attempt fails it returns the original error. I guess in your case the new primary was not elected yet, or at least the client was not aware about election results.

Comment: Try to set "primaryPreferred" read preferences. It should help with such scenarios. By default it reads strictly from primary to improve consistency. If you are okay with possibility to read stale data, relax read preferences. Otherwise you will need to handle such errors on application level.

Comment: Makes sense. So, to be clear, the above code should be fine either way, the problem is likely stemming from a "late election" and too strict a read preference?

Comment: Yes, "likely" is the very precise word. You will need server logs to evidence that. It might be something different but definitely not the getMore exclusion from the retryable reads. And to make it crystal clear read strictly from primary is the default read preference for a reason. Please ensure you understand consequences of allowing reads from secondaries. There is a bunch of additional parameters to mitigate the risks: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#mongodb-readmode-primaryPreferred

Comment: Yes, I understand read preferences. Actually, looking into it, this particular component is already set to *secondary preferred*, so that should already be as good as it gets for this case… 

Comment: oh, it just makes it a bit more interesting. I would check if there were any network problems on mongodb side then. The re-election might be a symptom not the trigger. But considering it's Atlas you will need help from their support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rescue whatever exception the driver raises on a network error outside of this code and repeat the entire iteration in that case.

The driver automatically retries initial queries but not getMores, because those don't have a way of specifying the position in the result set. Thus the driver's retryable reads logic is insufficient for a robust application, you still need to handle the possibility of read errors in your application on the level of complete iterations.

If you are retrieving a single document, it should generally be included in the initial query response and no getMores would be needed, thus in practice this question wouldn't apply.

Comment: What's the "aggregate is retryable" all about then?

Comment: The initial query is retryable by the driver.

Comment: So, if the connection is already gone when I'm about to send the `aggregate` query, *that* will be retried, but if the database goes down between the `aggregate` finishing and me retrieving the result, it won't?

Comment: The driver performs one retry. That's two network errors.

Comment: @deceze It will. It may look like querying and retrieving results are 2 different actions on pymongo API but on the wire your aggregate "finishing" packet already contains documents https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#op_reply. Any network error that happens until you receive OP_REPLY to your aggregation query will trigger the retry. Once.

Comment: So it shouldn't make any difference _when_ the connection disappears (before or right after the `aggregate` call), the auto-retry should work. Given that the error was explicitly raised on the `await cursor.fetch_next` line, my only explanation would be that that does trigger a getMore, whether the driver has gotten results or not. Avoiding that explicit `fetch_next` should therefore possibly remove that possibility for failure?

Comment: @deceze, yep you're right. It doesn't matter. The fetch_next is motor specific, not sure how it works. If implementation is similar to nodejs promises, you get the python object straight after the OP_QUERY is sent. The await will block execution until OP_REPLY is received.

Comment: Just checked, motor's aggregate() returns _LatentCursor https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/512b3cc0a975d0bc60b776e51b740c86235a8a5f/motor/core.py#L572, basically you get your cursor object before the query is sent to Atlas. Even if you already lost connectivity at the time of calling aggregate()  you won't get an error until you await the results.